# Magento2.4.0 - How to install latest version of Elasticsearch on hosting server

Tags: magento2, installation, elasticsearch, magento2.4, magento2.4.0

I have started a website build in `Magento2.4`.

How to check that `Elasticsearch` is installed `Magento2.4` packages I have installed on my hosting server.

Please share command that I can run with ssh.

If it is not installed please share how do I install.

I have checked my admin panel setting & `Elasticsearch` connection is always getting failed with `no alive nodes found in your cluster error`.

Please fix this issue.

Please share details that relates to windows machine because I am running my magento site on windows machine.

I have to run my website soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can check elasticsearch is installed or not using the below command:

```
curl -XGET '<host>:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
```

If you haven't installed elastic search yet, you can install it using this reference link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html

For more detail information please refer Magento dev docs guide: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html#es-install-es6

Thanks

Comment: How to install JDK on hosting server first with ssh

Comment: Please refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html#prereq-java

This reference link has commands to install JDK as per Installed OS.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I already checked this link but did not find windows or ssh link

Comment: Which OS is installed on the server where Magento 2.4.0 is installed?

Comment: I have a linux hosting but I m using admin panel and all on windows 7

Comment: You need to contact your hosting provider and tell them to install JDK as well as Elastic search on your server.

Comment: I found one more link to install JDK on windows. Can you please refer to it? It might help you.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-371F38CC-248F-49EC-BB9C-C37FC89E52A0